# В чем отличие uml- диаграммы от er- диаграммы при моделировании базы данных?

Tags: uml

В чем отличие uml- диаграммы от er-диаграммы при моделировании базы данных? И посоветуйте ещё какую-нибудь литературу почитать про это и как моделировать

Answer (score 0):

UML-диаграммы используют в ООП

ER-диаграммы для проектирования БД на концептуальном уровне